# Creating separate table to keep track of a specific column using TIMESTAMP data type

Tags: mysql, database-design

I've a mysql table which has two columns changes frequently.
One is  "available"(mainly 0,1) & the other is  "notification_preference".
Now, I wanna create a "updated_at" column to keep track of of the changes of "available" column.

**I've learnt that TIMESTAMP type updates automatically if a column of the corresponding row changes. I want to use "updated_at" column to keep track only of the "available" column.**

So the question is, **should I create a new table with "available" & "updated_at(TIMESTAMP)" or keep data in the same table and change the "updated_at" table manually?**
The main table is the following :

...........................................

id                int

name              varchar

username          varchar

password          varchar

available         tinyint

updated_at        DATETIME

***What I'm wanting to do is :***

**Main Table**

...........................................

id                int

name              varchar

username          varchar

password          varchar

available         tinyint

updated_at        DATETIME

**Another Table for available**

...........................................

user_id

available         tinyint

updated_at        TIMESTAMP

which procedure is better?

**There are other columns in the main table that might change sometimes, so I can't use TIMESTAMP for "updated_at" in the main table. Because if other columns of this table get updated, then "updated_at" will be updated too, but I don't want this.
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Do you need to keep track of every `updated_at` value, or just the latest one?

Comment: Last when the available column was updated.

Comment: You didn't get my question @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen remove the duplicate mark!

Comment: Edit your question and show us data which demonstrates your problem.  It isn't clear what you want to do here.

Comment: Edit your question and show us data which demonstrates your problem.  It isn't clear what you want to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trigger which will update the `updated_at` column only if the value in `available` has been changed:

```
create trigger mainTable_before_update before update on mainTable
for each row begin
    if new.available <> old.available
        then set new.updated_at = now();
    end if;
end
```

For inserts you can still use `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the CREATE statement:

```
updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

As you will see in the [Demo](http://rextester.com/WRVG60869) the column is not updated when we change the password. But it is updated when we change `available`.